# C# - how to implement an image preloading cache with threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my application, there is a list of images through which the user can step. Image loading is slow, so to improve user experience I would like to preload some images in the background (e.g. those images in the list succeeding the currently selected one).

I've never really used threads in C#, so I am looking for some kind of "best practice" advice how to implement the following behaviour:

```
public Image LoadCachedImage(string path) 
{
    // check if the cache (being operated in the background)
    // has preloaded the image
    Image result = TryGetFromCache(path);

    if (result == null) { result = LoadSynchronously(path); }

    // somehow get a list of images that should be preloaded,
    // e.g. the successors in the list
    string[] candidates = GetCandidates(path);

    // trigger loading of "candidates" in the background, so they will
    // be in the cache when queried later
    EnqueueForPreloading(candidates);

    return result;   
}
```

I believe, a background thread should be monitoring the queue, and consecutively process the elements that are posted through EnqueueForPreloading(). I would like to know how to implement this "main loop" of the background worker thread (or maybe there is a better way to do this?)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need sequential processing of the candidates, you can do one of the following:

1. Create a message queue data structure that has a AutoResetEvent. The class should spawn a thread that waits on the event and then processes everything in the queue. The class's Add or Enqueue should add it to the queue and then set the event. This would release the thread, which processes the items in the queue.
2. Create a class that starts an STA thread, creates a System.Windows.Forms.Control, and then enters Application.Run(). Every time you want to process an image asynchronously, call Control.BeginInvoke(...) and the STA thread will pick it up in its message queue.

There are probably other alternatives, but these two would be what I would try.

If you don't actually need sequential processing, consider using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...). If there are free pool threads, it will use them, otherwise it will queue up the items. But you won't be guaranteed order of processing, and several may/will get processed concurrently.

Here's a (flawed) example of a message queue:

```
class MyBackgroundQueue<T>
{
    private Queue<T> _queue = new Queue<T>();
    private System.Threading.AutoResetEvent _event = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);
    private System.Threading.Thread _thread;

    public void Start()
    {
        _thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ProcessQueueWorker));
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public class ItemEventArgs : EventArgs
    { public T Item { get; set; } }

    public event EventHandler<ItemEventArgs> ProcessItem;

    private void ProcessQueueWorker()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _event.WaitOne();
            while (_queue.Count > 0)
                ProcessItem(this, new ItemEventArgs { Item = _queue.Dequeue() });
        }
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(item);
        _event.Set();
    }
}
```

One flaw here, of course, are that _queue is not locked so you'll run into race conditions. But I'll leave it to you to fix that (e.g. use the 2 queue swap method). Also, the while(true) never breaks, but I hope the sample serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I call cheat caching.  The operating system already caches files for you, but you have to access them first.  So what you can do is just load the files but don't save a reference to them.

You can do this without multi-threading per-se, and without holding the images in a list.  Just create a method delegate and invoke for each file you want to load in the background.

For example, pre-loading all the jpeg images in a directory.

```
Action<string> d = (string file) => { System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file); };
foreach(string file in dir.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
    d.BeginInvoke(file);
```

BeginInvoke() is a multi-threaded approach to this, that loop will go very fast, but each file will be loaded on a different thread.  Or you could change that up a little to put the loop inside the delegate, aka.

```
public void PreCache(List<string> files)
{
    foreach(string file in files)
         System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file);
}
```

Then in your code

```
Action<List<string>> d = PreCache;
d.BeginInvoke(theList);
```

Then all the loading is done on just one worker thread.

Comment: BeginInvoke does not do anything "on a different thread".  To the contrary, it let's you do something specifically on the UI thread.  It basically says "call this method on the UI thread the next time the UI thread isn't busy doing other stuff".  While your invoked method is then executing on the UI thread, the UI thread can't do other things - it will appear unreponsive.  So... your first suggestion will work fine but the second one will not.